# Error when switch flash light on android javacameraview

Tags: android, flash, opencv

I am using OpenCV4Android in my project and i am using JavaCameraView. I tried to switch my phone flash light but failed. Here is my attempts.

```
public class Camera_View extends JavaCameraView {

private static final String TAG = "Camera View";
public boolean isFlashOn = false;

public Camera_View(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public List<String> getEffectList() {
    return mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedColorEffects();
}

public boolean isEffectSupported() {
    return (mCamera.getParameters().getColorEffect() != null);
}

public String getEffect() {
    return mCamera.getParameters().getColorEffect();
}

public void setEffect(String effect) {
    Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
    params.setColorEffect(effect);
    mCamera.setParameters(params);
}

public List<Size> getResolutionList() {
    return mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
}

public void setResolution(Size resolution) {
    disconnectCamera();
    mMaxHeight = resolution.height;
    mMaxWidth = resolution.width;
    connectCamera(getWidth(), getHeight());
}

public Size getResolution() {
    return mCamera.getParameters().getPreviewSize();
}

public void switchFlash(boolean flash_on) {
    Parameters p = mCamera.getParameters();
    if (!flash_on)
        p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
    else
        p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
    mCamera.setParameters(p);
}

public void switchFlash() {
    Camera  tcamera = null;
    tcamera = Camera.open();
    Parameters p = tcamera.getParameters();
    if (isFlashOn)
        p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
    else
        p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
    isFlashOn = !isFlashOn;
    tcamera.setParameters(p);
}

public void setupCameraFlashLight(boolean flash_on) {
    Camera camera = mCamera;
    if (camera != null) {
        Parameters params = camera.getParameters();

        if (params != null) {
            if (!flash_on) {
                isFlashOn = false;
                params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                camera.setParameters(params);
                camera.startPreview();
            } else {
                isFlashOn = true;
                params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                camera.setParameters(params);
                camera.startPreview();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I try to switch the flash light on or off using three method. But seem likes what i found online is for nativeCameraView but i am using JavaCameraView. When i try to run the coding, i got java.lang.NullPointerException.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: How this code even compile? `mCamera` has not beed declared nor initialized.

Comment: When i go to declaration, it directs me to opencv\android\JavaCameraView. mCamera has been declare inside here.